# licensing consideration of using itextsharp in a saas project

Tags: licensing, itext

I might need to use iTextSharp for a project I'm working on. I'd prefer to use the latest version so I'm trying to understand what the full implications of the GNU Affero General Public License is. I've read though the FSF documents but still have questions. I'm not going to modify it in any way, just call it from a component (windows service) that I've written. This component references other modules from the product I work on.

Currently the component is deployed on a server which runs website instances of the product for our clients. The component does work for all of the sites. We don't plan on distributing the product to clients yet, but it is on our roadmap for the future.

Would the component come under the GNU Affero General Public License when I use iTextSharp and therefore need to be made available for download? Would the other modules from the product referenced by my component come under the license as well?

Basically for the situation I've outlined above what would I need to do to keep within the licence agreement?

Thanks

K

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i was also looking into using iTextSharp in a web application.

However the following paragraph from http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/ clarified the licensing implications:

> Buying such a license is mandatory as soon as you develop commercial activities involving the iText software without disclosing the source code of your own applications. These activities include: offering paid services to customers as an ASP, serving PDFs on the fly in a web application, shipping iText with a closed source product.

Regards.

Comment: what if I made the source code of the module that uses it (which is a windows service) available? Would I need to include the source code of all my other projects that the module references?

Comment: i'm no lawyer but "disclosing the source code of your own applications" IMO implies the entirety of the source code. If it was phrased slightly differently, like this: "disclosing source code of your own applications" the meaning would change dramatically. I dropped the definite article "the" from the phrase and it allows for a much wider range of interpretation. But. SEEK REAL LEGAL ADVICE!!! This isn't LawyerOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

iTextSharp uses the LGPL license agreement and not the Affero model, http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/PDF/iTextSharp/CatalogiTextSharp.htm , License:   GNU Library or Lesser General Public License (LGPL) says it right there.

iText is different from iTextSharp and both have separate licenses

Comment: True, that page says it the lgpl license but this page http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/develop says its the Affero gpl. I think its version 4 and before that was lgpl and version 5 that is affero GPL.

Comment: Ahh I was using version 4, all the more reason to stick with version 4 then.  Especially considering lgpl allows you to package it with a sold product and just provide source and notification to the module that you used without making everything open like affero(At least, that's how I understand it)